# Change Default Table Style when opening a CSV file

Tags: numbers

#### Background

I often open a CSV file on **Numbers**, and then I see the table of which style is 'Basic'.

I want to use another style (e.g. 'Gray'), but it's annoying to change the style every time I open a file.

#### Question

Can I change the default table style which Numbers uses when a file is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of the possibility of changing the default, but a useful workflow is:

- set up the doc with the exactly the styles you need,
- 'Save as template' to the template chooser,
- open Numbers
- new doc with your new template
- drag the CSV onto the table

Actually pretty quick to execute (after initial template configuration) and very flexible (allows different styles for different purposes). In combination Launchbar (etc), this is pretty seamless and doesn't involve any messing about with positioning windows, etc.